# Find out if CA ARCserve Backup is currently running

Tags: backup

How can I look up if ArcServe is currently running? In "Quick Start" -> "Job Status" -> "Activity Log" I can only see the `Generic Logs`. There is no entry for the current day (each day a backup should be made). If I look at the tape the LED only shows `Ready`. In "Infrastructure Visualization" I see two nodes with the status `Not Attempted`.

Can it be that the current backup doesn't show up in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file should be current even if the job is running. Go to the Job Status Monitor from your ArcServe Dashboard. You should see a visual display of the jobs that are RUNNING, ON HOLD or READY. This is the easiest way to find out if a job is running.